# MIT/GNU Scheme hash-table/modify! arguments

Tags: scheme

How to modify a hash table? I found the hash-table/modify! function, but it's not officially documented so I cannot figure out its arguments. It should be something like this:

```
(hash-table/modify! hashtable key (lambda (datum) (do-smth)) smth-else)
```

Unfortunately, I don't know what should be the fourth argument. Is there a better (official) way to update a hash table? Should I try some other scheme interpreter? By the way, if it helps, I ran into this problem while coding http://projecteuler.net/problem=62 . Also, I am pretty new to scheme in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Basic hash tables SRFI-69](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-69/srfi-69.html), specifically   [hash-table-set!](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-69/srfi-69.html#hsht5) and [hash-table-update!](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-69/srfi-69.html#hsht8).